# Проверять input и в зависимости от значения выводить текст

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте. Есть input, при вводе текста в который, выводит подсказки из уже имеющегося массива слов.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <form action="a.php" method="post" />
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" name="text">
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Вопрос: Как сделать, чтобы если пользователь ввел в поле слово, которого нет в массиве со словами, нельзя было отправить форму, и кнопка submit не была видна, или заменялась текстом?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: вы как то пытались решить проблему то? Где ваш обработчик нажатия кнопки Submit или события ввода текста в поле, с последующей проверкой введенного текста по массиву?

Comment: @teran в js я не силен. поэтому прошу помощи) любой полезной информации которая натолкнет меня на решение задачи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать кнопку `submit` неактивной можно так:

```
$("#tags").keyup(function(){
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC"
    ];
    if(availableTags.indexOf($(this).val()) == -1 )
    {
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }else{
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Блокировать отправку формы можно так:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC"
   ];
    if(availableTags.indexOf($("#tags").val()) == -1 )
    {
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

При желании можете саму проверку сделать регистронезависимой, вынести её в отдельную функцию и добавить обработку события `onchange`.

Comment: кнопка не активна, но при вводе значения которое есть в массиве - она активной не становится

Comment: @Денис, очень даже становится https://jsfiddle.net/en7k5n2k/

Comment: а можно ли как-то не обращать внимания на регистр букв?

Comment: и еще, в функции был **autocomplete** . я его добавил в ваш код, но при это при выборе из списка - кнопка активной не становиться. только если вводить полное слово

Comment: Она и не должна становиться активной при выборе из списка. Для этого я в ответе написал, что можно добавить обработчик события `onchange`. Регистронезависимой функцию проверки тоже сделать можно. Например, перебирать элементы в массива в цикле и сравнивать с введённым значением приводя и то, и другое к нижнему регистру.

Comment: если вас не затруднит, было бы здорово увидеть этот обработчик и функцию для него